# Permission denied in my O.S /etc/default/locale not configured

Tags: permissions, locale

I want help for my Ubuntu issue.

```
/ etc/default/locale: /etc/default/locale:Permission denied.
```

Why?
As root I enter `sh -x /usr/sbin/update-info-dir` and get this:

```
+INFODIR=/usr/share/info
+set -e/
+unset LANGUAGE
+unset LANG
+[ -r /etc/enviroment ]
+. /etc/enviroment
+PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
+[ -r /etc/default/locale]
+ ./etc/default/locale
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/default/locale: /etc/default/locale: Permission denied.
```

When I push locale Denislav view:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Should I configure Locale?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir`: The line

```
./etc/default/locale
```

should actually be

```
. /etc/default/locale
```

Note the space after the dot.

As root use

```
nano /usr/sbin/update-info-dir
```

(or whatever editor you prefer) and change that line.

Comment: Apart from these it looks like OP has wrong file "enviroment", shouldn't it be "environment"?